# UILabel letters from blurred background

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uilabel, blur

I want to have an UILabel in my App where the letters consist of blurred background, like you can see in the picture:
[image]

How can I achieve this effect? Is this possible with UIKit? Or any 3rd party libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking on how to do the blur effect itself or just on how to apply this effect on the UILabel?

Comment: I can blur an image for example with Apple's "UIImage+ImageEffects" class but how can I apply a blurred image to an UILabel?

Comment: Simple, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Blur the image and crop it to fit the frame of your text label (It would look more convincing this way) and then use `UIColor`'s  `colorWithPatternImage:` to set the `UILabel` text color;

```
[label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bluredImage]];
```

Comment: It would be difficult to fake convincingly the location to crop. Crop should be performed according to label frame in relation to the image bounds. Otherwise if an image is more colorful than the above, it would be clear that the blur is from a different region of the image.

Comment: Yep this is what I meant when I said to fit label frame not bounds. It only makes sense. Feel free to edit my answer if you think think the syntax is not clear.

Comment: Apple has their private backdrop layer which (if it was public API) is as simple as creating and adding as sublayer and the effect is achieved easily. Open Radar for them to add this feature in iOS8.